# How to create ScrollView with AutoLayout in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout

How to create `ScrollView` with `AutoLayout` in Xcode 6.3. While I create the scroll view it takes 600X 600 screen and doesnt change the view size according to the screen orientation. What is the best waay to acheive the `ScrollView` with `AutoLayout` . I have following code inside `ViewDidLoad`

```
[mainScrollView addSubview:contentView];
[mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,800)];
contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [Util window_width], 800);
```

I have following Nib file as shown below

> I have got the `contentview`

[image]

> `UIScrollView` is placed over `UIViewController`

[image]
[image]

Comment: This should provide everything you need to create a scrollview using auto layout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

Give the scroll view spacing constraints to all sides of the controller's view, then it will be whatever size the screen is.

You should never just drop a view into a controller without adding your own constraints when you're using the wAny hAny size class; the system will add constraints for you, and they will be origin at {0,0}, and width and height of 600 (assuming that you made the view full size) which doesn't correspond to any actual device.

Comment: can you show me steps by sep to do every things. i have done what you said but got the problem so that

Comment: @nischalhada Just select your view, then select the Pin icon at the bottom of the canvas. Click on the I-beams at the top of the window that comes up, then click on "add 4 constraints" at the bottom.